# Flutter: Java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to use the auth, firestore firebase in an Android / IOS flutter application, and have been experiencing many different issues, after testing several different versions. Now it's showing me several messages in the build log.

build log

> Note:
> D:\Flutter\SDK\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.3+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: D:\Flutter\SDK\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:unchecked for details. D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 81454 > 65536)
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
> merging dex archives:  The number of method references in a .dex file
> cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at
> https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
>
> ```
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>
>     at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
>
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
>     at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
>     at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
>     at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
> ```
>
> complete
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
> ... 34 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit
> requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 81454 > 65536)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
> ... 36 more
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> > The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> > Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4m 33s

flutter doctor -v

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-IN)

- • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at D:\Flutter\SDK\flutter

  > ```
  > • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
  > • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
  > • Dart version 2.7.0
  > ```

> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.2)

- • Android SDK at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

  > ```
  > • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
  > • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
  > • Java binary at: D:\Android SDK\jre\bin\java
  > • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
  > • All Android licenses accepted.
  > ```

> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)

- • Android Studio at D:\Android SDK

  > ```
  > • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
  > • Dart plugin version 191.8593
  > • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
  > ```

pubspec

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

build.gradle(android)

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Looks like not using proper versions of plugins, showing flutter doctor -v and pubspec.yaml would help further analyze the problem

Comment: thanx in advance

Comment: Run `Flutter clean`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use the following plugin:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

Don't forget to configure firebase:

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#setup

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#usage

Also in your `app/build.gradle`, increase the `minSdkVersion`:

Change this:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

into this:

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: I did use the following plugins

Comment: the same version? Also did u setup firebase before adding these plugins?

Comment: execute flutter clean, when you added did u do pub get?

Comment: Execute flutter doctor and add the output here

Comment: ive edited the question, added pubspec depends and flutter doctor -v

Comment: Add ur build.gradle also

Comment: In ur app/build.gradle what is the minimumsdkversion u are using?

Comment: 16 , targetsdkversion is 28

Comment: Increase it to 23

Answer (score 6):

In order to use **minSdkVersion** below 21 you will have to configure your app for multidex like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

After this please run the

```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter clean
flutter run
```

It will still throw the warning after **flutter clean**, but at least it will be possible for supporting earlier versions.
More to check out on [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Open terminal and Run:

1. Run: flutter clean => Clean cache.
2. Run: flutter pub outdated => Findout what libraries need to upgrade.
3. Run: flutter pub upgrade => Upgrade libraries.
4. Run: flutter pub get.
5. Run: flutter run.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also got errors with my project when using Firebase services(core, auth, cloud firestore), but I decided to get into this problem only when building an appbundle:

[image: screen with error in the console]

fixed it with part of the chosen answer, by increasing **minSdkVersion** in *android/app/build.gradle*

from:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    ...
}
```

to:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 23
    ...
}
```

Аnd then the error that I get of project building disappears:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In this case, There are two things are responsible:

1. The package/plugin owner uses **older version of flutter SDK** or may uses older version of library in his/her **package's pubspec.yaml** file.
2. You can give a try to **flutter upgrade (Which upgrades your flutter SDK version)**, **Flutter Pub Upgrade(Which upgrades your pubspec dependecies)** and increasing your **minSdkVersion**.

- And still if you are facing this issue then you shall find alternative of used packages. But in most of the cases it gives you warnings not an error.

Happy Fluttering!!