# why having this error 'deprecated API' when trying added firebase to flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am Facing error while trying to add Firebase on Flutter project.
when I run the app error appear:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core- 
 1.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or 
  overrides a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore- 
1.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java 
  uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore- 1.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler. 
   java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-  1.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or 
 overrides a deprecated API.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50487/Plr_UpKjauM=/ws
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these things, or a combination of them, should send your problem away

1. Upgrade your build version to 23 in `android/app/build.grade` file
2. `flutter clean`
3. In `android/app/build.grade`, update dependencies like

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

4. Run `flutter pub upgrade` in terminal or pub upgrade from the pubspec.yaml file
5. Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531270/13858991

Will check on some more known ways to fix it and let you know when I update the answer

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. The app should function completely fine even with this warning but warning should not be there, so lets try and fix it.Paste the output of flutter run -Xlint:deprecation . Also add the dependencies you are using (From the pubspec.yaml)

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1

Comment: Did the error come instantly after you did something different or out of no where?

Comment: I just follow the instructions of integrate firebase, I didn't really do anything !

Comment: Did u initialize the app with Firebase.initializeApp()? Add the .json file? Edit the build.gradle files completely? I am going to look into this deeply tommorow but please upload the code you are using so I can create it on my device too

Comment: Sir ,I didn't use firebase yet  I just added firebase to my project and run main.dart !

Comment: execute flutter doctor in the terminal and post to the question what do you get and do flutter clean also after changing to minsdkversion 23