# ?The application is working but there is an error in firebase_auth and firebase_core_web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth_web-0.1.3+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth_web\FirebaseAuthWebPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase_core_web\FirebaseCoreWebPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: This is not an error, it's a warning message. [Check out this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529428/flutter-java-uses-or-overrides-a-deprecated-api)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a problem for you, just keep writing your code.

Kudos.