# FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

When it compiling my app of flutter with firebase it show this warning:

> Note: C:\Users\raul\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\raul\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

I have try fix it configurating the dependence in the grandle Android/app/build.grandle:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" // Agrega esta línea
    }
    ...
}
```

but continous with the same warning, i have search that it configure the Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details, but i dont exactly how.

How can fix it, or really is a problem program without Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.?

Comment: have you tried adding       multiDexEnabled true

Comment: yes i have tried

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same result only when attempting to compile via the terminal build command...

```
flutter build apk
```

I found the answer in a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531270/3607271

The point that fixed it for me was increasing the minSdkVersion ...

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: no, did not solve the problem