# Handling compile errors in flutter and VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run a flutter app in VSCode that I have not run for quite a couple of years. When I try to run in debug mode I get the following error in the debug console and I don't know what they mean or how to fix them.

Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software
rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Note: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.9.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.9.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.6.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            139.7s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...           6.1s
E/flutter (14905): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(113)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
E/flutter (14905): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (14905): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(436)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (14905): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(637)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

I ran flutter doctor and there were no issues.
Next, I ran flutter clean and then flutter run.
I upgraded all the dependencies.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix these errors?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem.
Change this:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

into this:

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531270/9152411)